# How do you implement rgamma and dgamma in a single plot

Tags: r

For an assignment I was asked this:

> For the values of
>   (shape=5,rate=1),(shape=50,rate=10),(shape=.5,rate=.1), plot the
>   histogram of a random sample of size 10000. Use a density rather than
>   a frequency histogram so that you can add in a line for the population
>   density (hint: you will use both rgamma and dgamma to make this plot).
>   Add an abline for the population and sample mean. Also, add a subtitle
>   that reports the population variance as well as the sample variance.

My current code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
x = seq(1, 1000)
s = 5
r = 1
plot(x, dgamma(x, shape = s, rate = r), rgamma(x, shape = s, rate = r), sub = 
paste0("Shape = ", s, "Rate = ", r), type = "l", ylab = "Density", xlab = "", main = 
"Gamma Distribution of N = 1000")
```

After running it I get this error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I was going to plot a histogram with ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot()` does not take y1 and y2 arguments.  See `?plot`.  You need to do a plot (or histogram) of one y variable (e.g., from rgamma), then add the second y variable (e.g., from dgamma) using something like `lines()`.

Here's one way to get a what you want:

```
#specify parameters
s = 5
r = 1

# plot histogram of random draws
set.seed(1234)
N = 1000
hist(rgamma(N, shape=s, rate=r), breaks=100, freq=FALSE)

# add true density curve
x = seq(from=0, to=20, by=0.1)
lines(x=x, y=dgamma(x, shape=s, rate=r))
```

Comment: You can also use `lines`: `lines(x=x, y=dgamma(x, shape=s, rate=r))`

Comment: I like that better @see-king_of_knowledge, I've updated my answer to use `lines()`.